# How to display formatted xml text in a bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, html, xml, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have some data formatted in xml way and I need to display it in a popover's content. The xml tags are interpreted as html tags...

> `<Document><and><age>50</age><always/></and></document>`

I want to display xml as simple text and to be indented. Is there a way to do that?

So result should be:

```
    <Document>
       <and>
           <age>50</age>
           <always/>
      </and>
   </document>
```

Thank a lot.

Comment: Use the html option: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [pre](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag for this in the following way:
`<pre lang="xml"><your xml here></pre>`
Also set the html option to true in the options of the popover.